# Why does C# generate garbage when using a struct as a generic dictionary key?

Tags: c#, dictionary, garbage-collection

I have a generic dictionary of a struct as key and a class reference as a value.

```
Dictionary<IntVector2, SpriteRenderer> tileRendererMap;
```

I retrieve a reference to the renderer via the coordinates and change it like so:

```
tileRendererMap[tileCoord].color = Color.cyan;
```

This generates 0.8KB of garbage each time I use it. Is this the default behaviour? I would think that dictionary lookup would be one of the most performant things to do. I need to find a way around this, since I'm working for mobile platform and it's a critical system.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong or how to get allocation-free lookup?

**Edit after more testing:**

Using an *int* as key instead of my custom struct works as expected. No allocations, no problems and I don't think it's a weird thing to use an id as a key. However, for my game I want to store the renderer associated with a specific tile in a grid, which doesn't actually need to be any type of object, because I only care about the grid position. Hence, I thought an IntVector2 might be a practical identifier, but I could work around it, if I had to.

When using my struct I get allocations, which I measure with the Unity3D Profiler. It reports 0.8KB in *Dictionary_get_item*, specifically *DefaultComparer.Equals()*. Apparently it's a boxing/unboxing issue, but even when I implement my custom overrides, it still generates garbage, only a little less than before.

My basic struct implementation:

```
public struct IntVector2
{
    public int x, y;

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null || obj is IntVector2 == false)
            return false;

        var data = (IntVector2)obj;
        return x == data.x && y == data.y;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return x.GetHashCode() ^ y.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

**Edit after accepted answer:**

The allocation-free version of my struct when used in a generic dictionar.

```
public struct IntVector2 : IEquatable<IntVector2>
{
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public IntVector2(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public bool Equals(IntVector2 other)
    {
        return x == other.x && y == other.y;
    }
}
```

The *Dictionary* class uses the *IEquatable* interface instead of the *object* override *Equals*, which is why my first implementation was boxing one of the values each time it checked for equality when searching for the key.

Comment: The 0.8kb garbage should automatically get collected when required.

Comment: How did you determine that 0.8 kb of garbage was created? Did you analyze what that garbage contained of types?

Comment: It doesn't generate any garbage at all, you are merely setting a property on the SpriteRenderer object.  Pretty unlikely that a "color" is a reference type and even unlikelier that it would take 800 bytes.  There is something wrong with the way you measure garbage.

Comment: I am using the Unity 3D Profiler for measurement. It reports allocations in dictionary_get_item, specifically in the DefaultComparer Equals method. I am now testing if I can get different results by changing the comparer around.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since you only override `Equals`, and don't implement `IEquatable<IntVector2>`, the dictionary is forced to box one of the two instances whenever it compares two of them for equality, since it's passing an instance into an `Equals` method accepting `object`.

If you implement `IEquatable<IntVector2>` then the dictionary can (and will) use the version of `Equals` that accepts the parameter as an `IntVector2`, which won't require boxing.

Comment: This did it. From the profiler message I deduced it was calling the regular override Equals, but with the interface it does become a garbage free call. Exactly what I was hoping for. I should still rethink if the dictionary key makes sense in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Your `IntVector2` is a `struct` type. Not sure what's the point of using a `struct` as a dictionary key though? Do remember `struct` are value type and so will get value copied for each key and based on the size of that struct may generate that memory footprint.

You may probably want to use a particular property of that struct like. Example your struct

```
public struct IntVector2
{
  string key;
}
```

Then you can use that property rather like

```
Dictionary<string, SpriteRenderer> tileRendererMap;

Intvector2 iv2 = new Intvector2();
iv2.key = "test";

tileRendererMap = new Dictionary<string, SpriteRenderer>();
tileRendererMap.Add(iv2.key, new SpriteRenderer{prop1 = value});
```

Comment: So *assigning* a value to a dictionary key that is a struct constructs a brand new struct for the key first, then assigns the new value to it? Why doesn't it just leave the immutable struct alone after finding it and assign the new dictionary value to it?

Comment: @Quantic - even though you're using square brackets around the key, you're still calling a method and passing the struct as a parameter, so it still has to be copied on to the stack.

Comment: “Not sure what's the point of using a struct as a dictionary key though?”... Well, people use `int` as a dictionary key all the time, and `int` is a struct.

Comment: @RichardIrons Ah that makes sense. I guess we need to know how is profiler works then, because copying the struct parameter to the stack shouldn't show up as "garbage" that the GC has to do anything with, right? Is OP just seeing stack memory usage grow and he's attributing it to "garbage"?

Comment: The Unity3D Profiler measures "GC Allocations", and it only reports something for my struct, not when using a class or primitive types like int. Apparently, I must be doing something wrong in my struct implementation. I'm also pretty sure, that the Profiler is only measuring what actually will be collected. I've created a clean test project to be absolutely sure I'm not seeing anything else.

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez, using a `INT` is different from using a self defined  struct since your defined struct could be much more complex and may require way more space than a `INT` which require just 4bytes. That's what I exactly mean with that statement.

Comment: @Quantic year, good point. Must be something about the struct.